# Convert ByteArray into String in Android DataBase

Tags: android, string, image

I Convert image in Bitmap and stored in Byte[] img.
like

```
String image_path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ImageOfDb/"+"abc"+".jpg";
File f= new File(image_path);
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

then

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
img=bos.toByteArray();
```

I Successfully insert and retrive Image from Sqlite database, but I need to retrieve Image in the form of string.

The code:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 if(insert_button==arg0)
       {
          // String temp=Base64.encodeToString(img, Base64.DEFAULT);
           ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
           cv.put("image", img);
           db.insert("tableimage", null, cv);
           Toast.makeText(this, "inserted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    else if(show_button== arg0)
    {
         String[] col={"image"};
        // c= db.rawQuery("Select * from tableimage", null);
         c=db.query("tableimage", col, null, null, null, null, null);
         c.moveToFirst();
             if (c != null)
             {
                    //Move cursor to first row
                    if  (c.moveToFirst()) 
                    {
                        do {
                            //Get version from Cursor
                           // String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("image"));
                             img=c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("image"));
                           // db.close();
                            //Add the version to Arraylist 'results'
                           //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }while (c.moveToNext()); //Move to next row

                    }



                     Bitmap b1=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
                     imageviewretrive.setImageBitmap(b1);
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }


    }
}
```

My question is: "How can we retrieve image in the form of String and set this string in the ImageView?"

Comment: Why are you saving an image as a String? That's going to cause problems. You need to save it as binary data (in a BLOB field).

Comment: Thanks Erik for Quick Reply.

Comment: Is There any method  to show data which is saved in Sqlitedata base in the form of ByteArray.

Comment: save image as base64 encoded, when you retreive it you have to base64 decode to use image.